# How to merge data from two different api endpoints for each element returned?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem that I don't know how to resolve. I'm going to simplify it so that I can explain it better.

I have one API endpoint that returns me a list of persons, and other API endpoint where i can ask for the pets that a person has using the person ID (something like: api/pets/:person_id/).

The api for query the persons returns me an array that looks something like this:

```
[
    { 
        person_id: 123, 
        name: "John Abc"
    }, 
    ...
]
```

What I need is to add the array of pets for each element/person that the api of persons returns me, so that I end with something like this:

```
[
    { 
        person_id: 123, 
        name: "John Abc",
        pets: [
            { pet_id: 5, pet_name: 'doggy' },
            { pet_id: 7, pet_name: 'foobar' },
            ...
        ]
    }, 
    ...
]
```

I'm new to RxJs, I have read about different operators but this is something more complex that I have done previously. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946886/merge-two-dependent-api-calls-in-angular-with-observables-rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the response of `IPeople` into a list of Pet calls that mix the two together.

That might look like this:

```js
this.httpClient.get<IPerson[]>('/persons').pipe(
  map(people => people.map(person => 
    this.httpClient.get<IPet[]>(`/pets/${person.id}`).pipe(
      map(pets => ({
        ...person,
        pets
      }))
    )
  )),
  switchMap(calls => forkJoin(calls))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

You can also combine the `map` and `switchMap` into one call like this:

```js
this.httpClient.get<IPerson[]>('/persons').pipe(
  switchMap(people => forkJoin(
    people.map(person => 
      this.httpClient.get<IPet[]>(`/pets/${person.id}`).pipe(
        map(pets => ({
          ...person,
          pets
        }))
      )
    )
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

---

You can generally define smaller pieces of your transformation separately to make things a bit easier to follow/read. Up to you.

```js
/***
 * Returns an observable that add an array of pets to the given person
 ***/
function addPets(person: IPerson): Observable<IPerson>{
  return this.httpClient.get<IPet[]>(`/pets/${person.id}`).pipe(
    map(pets => ({
      ...person,
      pets
    }))
  );
}

/***
 * Print an array of people (with their pets included) to the console
 ***/
this.httpClient.get<IPerson[]>('/persons').pipe(
  switchMap(people => forkJoin(
    people.map(person => addPets(person))
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks!! Perfectly explained also.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you receive the data from your backend.

Assuming that the data for `pets` is received differently from that of `persons`

```typescript
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IPet {
  pet_id: number;
  pet_name: string;
}
interface IPerson {
  person_id: number;
  name: string;
  pets?: IPet[]
}

export MyComponentClass {
  pets$: Observable<IPet[]> = this.httpClient.get<IPet[]>('/pets');
  persons$: Observable<IPerson[]> = this.httpClient.get<IPerson[]>('/persons');
  personsWithPets$: IPerson = combineLatest([this.persons$, this.pets$]).pipe(
     map(([persons, pets]) => this.persons.map(person => 
       ({...person, pets: pets.filter(({person_id}) =>pet.person_id === person_id )}))
     )
  )
  persons: IPerson[];

  ngOnInit () {
    personsWithPets$.subscribe({
      next: persons => this.persons = persons
    })
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**

For your use case, you can follow the below steps

1. Get all `persons`
2. Use higher order observable such as `mergeMap` or `switchMap` to make a second resquest for `person`'s `pets`
3. Combine results of the two

```typescript
  persons$ = this.http.get<any>('/persons').pipe(
    mergeMap(persons => forkJoin([
      of(persons),
      forkJoin(persons.map(person => 
      this.http.get(`persons/${person.id}/pets`)))
    ])),
    map(([persons, pets]) => persons.map((person, key) => ({
      ...person, pets:pets[key]
    })))
  )
```

Below is a [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wluxz2)

I am using [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to subscribe

Comment: I would switch out `combineLatest` for `forkJoin` :)

Comment: First of all thank you. But I cannot resolve my problem that way because as I stated in my question the endpoint for the pets requires the person_id in the url as a parameter: api/pets/:person_id/, ie: api/pets/123/. That's why I have such a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: yes @MrkSef that is a great advice, I am updating the solution