# How i can concatenate/merge multiple json from multiple same get request?

Tags: javascript, api, http

I need to merge the various answers I get with a get on the same API.
I need to use Javascript
I reiterate that I will get the same format for every GET API call. I just need to get a single json at the end as shown at the end of the question.
For example first request get me:

```
    {
        "data": [{
            "id": 10896584,
            "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
            "delivery_status": "delivered",
            "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
            "direction": "OUT",
            "country": "IT",
            "price": "0.000",
            "is_two_way": false,
            "receive_dlr": "",
            "webhook_url": "",
            "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
        }]
}
```

the second request give me:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 29384883,
        "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
        "delivery_status": "delivered",
        "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
        "direction": "OUT",
        "country": "IT",
        "price": "0.000",
        "is_two_way": false,
        "receive_dlr": "",
        "webhook_url": "",
        "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
    }]
 }
```

so i want merge this two response and get a json like:

```
  {
        "data": [{
            "id": 10896584,
            "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
            "delivery_status": "delivered",
            "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
            "direction": "OUT",
            "country": "IT",
            "price": "0.000",
            "is_two_way": false,
            "receive_dlr": "",
            "webhook_url": "",
            "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
            },
            {
            "id": 29384883,
            "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
            "delivery_status": "delivered",
            "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
            "direction": "OUT",
            "country": "IT",
            "price": "0.000",
            "is_two_way": false,
            "receive_dlr": "",
            "webhook_url": "",
            "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
            }
        ]}
   }
```

}

Comment: There's not enough details like which backend tech you're using. From what I understood, you can take idea from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427398/how-to-merge-data-from-two-different-api-endpoints-for-each-element-returned

Comment: I need to do it in pure javascript, as it is a simple one-off manual operation.

i do a fetch operation to my endpoint and i get this data.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
const response1 =    {
        "data": [{
            "id": 10896584,
            "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
            "delivery_status": "delivered",
            "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
            "direction": "OUT",
            "country": "IT",
            "price": "0.000",
            "is_two_way": false,
            "receive_dlr": "",
            "webhook_url": "",
            "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
        }]
};

const response2 = {
    "data": [{
        "id": 29384883,
        "recipient_id": "+393881903818",
        "delivery_status": "delivered",
        "verbose_delivery_status": "Delivered",
        "direction": "OUT",
        "country": "IT",
        "price": "0.000",
        "is_two_way": false,
        "receive_dlr": "",
        "webhook_url": "",
        "created_at": "2021-10-28T12:48:44+00:00"
    }]
 };
 
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response1));

result.data.push(...response2.data);

console.log(result);
```